# ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo() is returning NULL after recording the video. But the video does exist in the Movies folder

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult

I am trying to let the users of my record a video. Using the following code.

```
private fun handleRecordVideoRequest() {
    val videoName = getVideoName()
    val videoUri = getVideoUri(videoName)
    Timber.tag(TAG).i(">>>> Video URI: $videoUri")
    val videoRecorder = getVideoRecorder()
    videoRecorder.launch(videoUri)
}

private fun getVideoRecorder() =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo()) { bitmap ->
    Timber.tag(TAG).i(">>>> Video Bitmap: $bitmap") // bitmap is NULL
}

private fun getVideoUri(videoName: String): Uri? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val videoStore = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        val newVideoDetails = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoName)
        }
        contentResolver.insert(videoStore, newVideoDetails)
    } else {
        val mediaDir = getExternalFilesDir("video/*")
        mediaDir?.mkdirs()
        val sdImageMainDirectory = File(mediaDir, videoName)
        FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, applicationContext.packageName + ".provider", sdImageMainDirectory)
    }
}

private fun getVideoName() = "app_video_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4"
```

The code runs without any exceptions being thrown. However the bitmap in method `getVideoRecorder()` is always `null`. When I view the folders on the emulator I can see that the video was recorded successfully.

I also have the write to storage permission enabled.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the implementation of the .ActivityResultContracts.TakeVideo contract you'll see that the result type is actually nullable.

The parseResult method will return null if 1. the resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK and 2. if intent.getParcelableExtra("data") is not a Bitmap.

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public final Bitmap parseResult(int resultCode, @Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return null;
        return intent.getParcelableExtra("data");
    }
```

I ran into the same issue on Android 11(Q) because the contents of the resulting Intent is the URI passed in; not a Bitmap. So.. I'd suggest just using ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult() instead.

Like so:

```
 val videoLauncher =
         registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { activityResult ->
                if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    activityResult.data?.data?.let {
                   // Do something with the video URI
                    }
                } else {
                    //handle user cancel
                }
            }
```

And use it:

```
fun captureVideo() {
mediaStoreService.createNewMediaFile(MediaAssetType.Video)?.let { uri ->
      Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE).apply {
             putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri)
             }.also { takeVideoIntent ->
                            takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(requireContext().packageManager)?.also {
                                videoLauncher.launch(takeVideoIntent)
                            }
                        }
                    }
}
```